# how can i fit a rectangular image inside a circular division in web page using css? what things should i keep in mind while attempting to do so?

Tags: html, css

i am a beginner who wants to learn please help.here archenemies is the id i gave to div.

---

```css
div {
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
 display: inline-block;
 margin-left: 5px;
 border-radius:100%;
 border: 2px solid black;
 
}
#archenemies{
  border:4px solid #cc0000;
  background-image:"http://static.comicvine.com/uploads/original/11119/111193741/4458205-1304230669-friez.png";
  background-size:90%;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Method 1 - Using Background Image.**

The things to keep in mind while creating a circular div-

**1. border-radius:50% or more**

**2. Backgound-imgage- size to cover**

**3. background position to center**

Below is the working code.

```css
div {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 5px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 2px solid black;
  border: 4px solid #cc0000;
  background-image: url(http://static.comicvine.com/uploads/original/11119/111193741/4458205-1304230669-friez.png);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
}
```

```html
<div> </div>
```

**Method 2 - Using IMG SRC**

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px
}

img {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 4px solid red
}
```

```html
<div><img src="http://static.comicvine.com/uploads/original/11119/111193741/4458205-1304230669-friez.png" /></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Sory if I ignored your height and width settings!

```css
.circle {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 100px;
    background-image: url('http://static.comicvine.com/uploads/original/11119/111193741/4458205-1304230669-friez.png') ;
    background-size: 100px;   
    background-position:50%;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
```

```html
<div class="circle"></div>
```